# Running Ubuntu on SSD with native hardware encryption enabled to work for eDrive (Windows' BitLocker enabled)

Tags: encryption, ssd, windows-10

I have Samsung 850 Evo. If I do a secure erase and then fresh install the Windows 10 (to enable the BitLocker to work with SSD's hardware encryption), will I able to install and use Ubuntu on it later?

850 Evo uses encryption in three ways:
Class 0 - ATA BIOS password setup
TG Opal - with third-party softwares
Encrypted Drive - to use with OS which supports "encrypted drive"